# How to delete an Object reference(children) when the the Parent Object is deleted in mongoose and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a program Model and the Program has many Comments. How can I delete the Comments when the Program is deleted? and how can I delete the I.D of a Comment from a Program when the comment is deleted, so that the Program does not keep an I.D of a comment that has already been deleted.

How do I delete children of an object when the object is deleted?

This is my Program Model.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const programSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   programtype: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
   },
   title: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
  },
  description: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  programImage: {
     type: String,
     require: true,
  },

  programcomments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Programcomment" }],
});
```

This is how it looks in the DB.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("6095483800384c72a32b573f"),
  "programcomments" : [
      ObjectId("6095488700384c72a32b5740"),
      ObjectId("60959fd27a728726d443e919"),
      ObjectId("60959fdd7a728726d443e91a")
  ],
  "title" : "Great is our God",
  "description" : "Jesus is Lord\" is the shortest credal affirmation found in the New,
  "programImage" : "https://-2.amazonaws.com/public/uploads/programImages/58373062_2123046797815766_3210886527940820992_n.jpg",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-07T14:01:28.483Z"),
"__v" : 3
}
```

This is my `Programomment` Model

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const programCommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
  },
  name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now,
  },
  program: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Program" },
});
```

And this is how it looks in my `DB`

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("60959fd27a728726d443e919"),
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-07T20:15:14.143Z"),
  "description" : "Comment App\n",
  "name" : "Chukwuma",
  "program" : ObjectId("6095483800384c72a32b573f"),
  "__v" : 0
 }
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("60959fdd7a728726d443e91a"),
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-07T20:15:25.858Z"),
  "description" : "Comment App\n",
  "name" : "Kingsley",
  "program" : ObjectId("6095483800384c72a32b573f"),
  "__v" : 0
}
```

I want all the `Programcomments` that are associated with a particular `Program` to delete automatically whenever the `Program` is deleted, and I also want the `I.D` of a `Programcomments` to delete automatically from the `Program` whenever a `programcomments` is deleted.

Comment: You can use middleware: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html